# Drawing a circle on a QWidget python GUI

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, touch-event, qpainter

I'm trying to draw a circle instead of dots
Here is the class where it paints red dots on pressing event at any place in the widget
I want to draw a circle (hollow circle) as an outline not  a solid circle that hide part of my picture

```
     import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *

        class Canvas(QWidget):

            def __init__(self, photo, *args, **kwargs):
                super().__init__(*

args, **kwargs)
            self.image = QImage(photo)
            self.setFixedSize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())

        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                qp = QPainter(self.image)
                qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
                qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 5))
                qp.setBrush(Qt.red)
                qp.drawPoint(event.pos())
                self.update()

        def paintEvent(self, event):
            qp = QPainter(self)
            rect = event.rect()
            qp.drawImage(rect, self.image, rect)


    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            w = QWidget()
            self.setCentralWidget(w)
            grid = QGridLayout(w)
            grid.addWidget(Canvas('photo.jpeg'))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        gui = MainWindow()
        gui.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I suppose that the second class definition was an involuntary paste, right? That said, I'm not sure I'm understanding your code: I can't see any painting, besides the `drawImage` function.

Comment: i just commented  the lines where it paints, and this is a sub-file where I import it into the main one having the GUI and other functions, I edited it and I added the function of load image

Comment: I still see a duplicate class with an indentation. Please review your example following the guidelines about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and check the preview before submitting the edit, otherwise it will be difficult for us to understand it.

Comment: here you are  ,i just put the class and attached the link I'm working on

Comment: I don't see you trying to draw a circle, where is that? Have you read the documentation about [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html)? Also, your indentation is wrong; as I already suggested, please check the preview before submitting any edit. We *must* be able to copy your code as it is, paste it and try to run it.

Comment: @HassanKhaledBosha provide a [mre]

Comment: @HassanKhaledBosha see drawEllipse

Comment: just check what i want to do now instead of dots I want an outlining circle

Comment: @HassanKhaledBosha https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt%5D+drawEllipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do.

[image]

In which case you need to take advantage of which paint device to pass to QPainter. During `mousePressEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent` use `QPainter(self)` so anything painted will only last until the next update. Then in `mouseReleaseEvent` when satisfied with the size of the circle, you can paint on the QImage with `QPainter(self.image)` to permanently draw the circle.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Canvas(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, photo, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.image = QImage(photo)
        self.setFixedSize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())
        self.pressed = self.moving = False
        self.revisions = []

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.pressed = True
            self.center = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.moving = True
            r = (event.pos().x() - self.center.x()) ** 2 + (event.pos().y() - self.center.y()) ** 2
            self.radius = r ** 0.5
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.revisions.append(self.image.copy())
            qp = QPainter(self.image)
            self.draw_circle(qp) if self.moving else self.draw_point(qp)
            self.pressed = self.moving = False
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        rect = event.rect()
        qp.drawImage(rect, self.image, rect)
        if self.moving:
            self.draw_circle(qp)
        elif self.pressed:
            self.draw_point(qp)

    def draw_point(self, qp):
        qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5))
        qp.drawPoint(self.center)

    def draw_circle(self, qp):
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 3, Qt.DashLine))
        qp.drawEllipse(self.center, self.radius, self.radius)

    def undo(self):
        if self.revisions:
            self.image = self.revisions.pop()
            self.update()

    def reset(self):
        if self.revisions:
            self.image = self.revisions[0]
            self.revisions.clear()
            self.update()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        w = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        canvas = Canvas('photo.png')
        grid = QGridLayout(w)
        grid.addWidget(canvas)
        QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+Z'), self, canvas.undo)
        QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+R'), self, canvas.reset)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MainWindow()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Yes that is completely perfect, can you tell me the function which reset it or delete the circle ?

Comment: @HassanKhaledBosha Do you mean you want to be able to undo the last circle and reset the image? Btw it is customary to approve the answer when it suitably answered your question.

Comment: I added undo (CTRL+Z) and reset (CTRL+R) functions.

Comment: yes a function to be used inside a function of push button_clicked to removed the circle

Comment: Ok I used hot key shortcuts but you can just connect the button clicked signal to `canvas.undo` and `canvas.reset` accordingly.

Comment: it's not working with the GUI even after I called the function reset in the pushButton_clicked function and also the shortcuts is not working , I made a function for the pushbutton and called Canvas.reset but it shows nothing

Comment: AttributeError: 'ApplicationWindow' object has no attribute 'revisions'
it gives me this error

Comment: @HassanKhaledBosha Copy my entire answer again not just the new functions.

Comment: i did so , check my answer to the post